# Remove Core Data Support From An App On The App Store

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, app-store, updates

I have an app on the App Store, and it is getting a decent amount of use. I'm doing things differently as I release updates, and want to completely remove core data from the application. How exactly do I go about doing that in the next released update?

Do I simply remove all the core data code in the AppDelegate file, and remove the data model file?

I want to be certain no units will crash as the new update is released.

Comment: I don't see how _not_ using something (your database file) could generate a crash, I would be more concerned that it got deleted properly so your app doesn't take up unnecessary disk space.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson How do I delete it properly?

Comment: it depends, but if its user data you have to make sure you migrate it in what ever you are using now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Option 1: just ignore it

This is by far the easiest solution.  Just leave the core data files on the user devices and they will just forever take up space for the user.  If the amount of data is small (less than 50mb), and the data stored in them has either already been transitioned or doesn't need to be, then this is a good option. You can remove all reference to core data from your app.

### Option 2: delete it in the background

You can delete it in the background when the app first runs.  Make a background context, fetch all objects, delete them, and save.  When done mark that it is done in NSUserDefaults and don't do it again.  If the amount of objects is very large it might require more complex code of batching the fetches and deletes. You need to retain at least the core data model, and possibly much more, in order for the delete to work.

### Option 3: transition the data

This is the hardest option because transition the data can take time, and if it takes too long iOS will force quit your app.  So first present a view controller explaining the user what is happening - and perhaps a progress indicator.  Then fetch the data in batches, save to you new store, delete it, and update your progress indicator. When all the transition is done, then update your view controller. Here you might need to retain a large amount of core-data code just to deal with this transition.